# Add a value into array and extend the loop iteration

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to push a value into a loop and move the cycle one or more step forward after the value is added. My problem is the value is replacing the current array value and not extending it forward. This is my code so far:

```
<?php
function getItem($date, $startDate){
  $item = array('a','b','c','b','c');
  $diff = date_create($startDate)->diff(date_create($date));
  if($diff->invert) return false; //error $date < $startDate
  return $item[$diff->days%5];
}

//example for use
$startDate = '2019-10-01';
$skipday = '2019-10-07';

$selected_start_date = '2019-10-01';
$selected_end_date = '2019-10-10';

$dates_array = array();
$current_date = strtotime($selected_start_date);
$last_date = strtotime($selected_end_date);

while( $current_date <= $last_date ) {
$dates_array[] = date('Y-m-d', $current_date);
$current_date = strtotime('+1 day', $current_date);     
}

for($i=0; $i<count($dates_array); $i++) {   
$today = $dates_array[$i];
$code = getItem($today, $startDate);

if($dates_array[$i] == $skipday) {
$code = "SKIP";
}

echo $today." ".$code."</br>";

}   
?>
```

```
This is my current Output :
2019-10-01 a
2019-10-02 b
2019-10-03 c
2019-10-04 b
2019-10-05 c
2019-10-06 a
2019-10-07 SKIP
2019-10-08 c
2019-10-09 b
2019-10-10 c

This is my Expected Output :
2019-10-01 a
2019-10-02 b
2019-10-03 c
2019-10-04 b
2019-10-05 c
2019-10-06 a
2019-10-07 SKIP
2019-10-08 b
2019-10-09 c
2019-10-10 b
```

What I want to achieve is the value after 2019-10-07 move forward and the cycle of array can be repeating as normal.

Comment: @NigelRen check my edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to make this work is to keep a count of skipped days and use that in the computation of `getItem`. So, change `getItem` to have a `$skipped_days` input:

```
function getItem($date, $startDate, $skipped_days){
  $item = array('a','b','c','b','c');
  $diff = date_create($startDate)->diff(date_create($date));
  if($diff->invert) return false; //error $date < $startDate
  return $item[($diff->days - $skipped_days) % 5];
}
```

count the number of skipped days in the code:

```
if($dates_array[$i] == $skipday) {
  $code = "SKIP";
  $skipped_days++;
}
```

and use that in the call to `getItem`:

```
$code = getItem($today, $startDate, $skipped_days);
```

Note you need to initialise `$skipped_days` to 0, this can be done when you set `$skipDay`:

```
$skipday = '2019-10-07';
$skipped_days = 0;
```

Output:

```
2019-10-01 a</br>
2019-10-02 b</br>
2019-10-03 c</br>
2019-10-04 b</br>
2019-10-05 c</br>
2019-10-06 a</br>
2019-10-07 SKIP</br>
2019-10-08 b</br>
2019-10-09 c</br>
2019-10-10 b</br>
```

Complete code and demo on [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/CK3f3)

Comment: Thanks bro and it's working.  return $item[($diff->days - $skipped_days) % 5]; is the way do it.

Comment: @EDDY good to hear. I think the advantage of this approach is that it will make it easier to expand skip days to an array if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you have that function and this may be oversimplifying it a bit, but in this code it puts the list `$item` into the main code and uses a counter to indicate which one to output.  If the item is to be skipped, it just decrements this counter again to re-use the item...

```
$item = array('a','b','c','b','c');
$itemCount = count($item);
$currentItem = 0;
for($i=0; $i<count($dates_array); $i++) {
    $today = $dates_array[$i];
    $code = $item[($currentItem++)%$itemCount];

    if($dates_array[$i] == $skipday) {
        $code = "SKIP";
        $currentItem--;
    }

    echo $today." ".$code."</br>";
}
```

Comment: I use the function because I want to share it on other pages later on as well. But yeah, your simple code works as well. I may need to convert it into a function. Thanks bro!